Convert changing name years after conversion
Chalom,
Is a convert allowed to change his name several years after his conversion if he wants?
For example, if another person chooses his name for him.
If his name chosen at the conversion in front of the Beit Din, is Avraham-Its'hak and he wants to change it, should he add a third name or can he replace one of them by an another one? In particular, if this convert is now divorced does that affect the answer?

I don't really remember Jews changing their names except due to Divine command or a very serious medical condition.

Surprisingly, AFAIK, Judaism has no notion of a census or registry, therefore, there are no limitations on changing one's name.

A convert is a Jew and a Jew is allowed to change his name. See detailed discussion with sources here: https://aish.com/changing-ones-name
